# sample mongoskin mocha test

Tags: mocha.js, mongoskin

I have a sample db 'rockband' with collection 'bands' with four docs. 
Here is a simple stub that works (coffee):

```
mongo     = require('mongoskin')

db = mongo.db('localhost:27017/rockband')
db.collection("bands").find().toArray (err, result) ->
  throw err  if err
  console.log result
```

This returns json with good data.

However, the following mocha test passes WITHOUT returning data or any complaints:

```
should = require("should")
mongo     = require('mongoskin')

describe "simple test", ->
  err = db = null
  before (done) ->
    db = mongo.db('localhost:27017/rockband')
    done()

  it "should pass", ->
    db.collection("bands").find().toArray (err, result) ->
      throw err  if err
      console.log result

    should.not.exist err
```

Any suggestions?